# Mobile Web tap background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, webkit

I want to achieve a tap background color effect on my web app, much like native apps do it (like gmail for iOS for example - when you tap to click through to an email, the background highlights in a blue color).

CSS :active works great on Android.

With iOS 9.3, apple removed the 350ms tap delay, which I was completely thrilled to find out! I removed fastclick.js with excitement. But then, when the user taps, :active doesn't seem to work whatsoever! Their developer forums are a joke. No one cares.

I tried adding fastclick.js back again, which makes :active work again on iOS - but then it triggers on scroll.

Natively there is probably a 50ms delay so it only highlights when tap through the link.

I thought that this CSS is intended for this purpose:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: #eee;
```

However, when I try to use this (in safari on iOS 9.3), it covers up all the content (text) on the element too (the entire element turns completely grey, text and all). Am I missing something? Why would the entire content of the div/element get covered when using this? Wouldn't its common usage be the background color?

UPDATE: I've rolled my own solution below. Hope this helps people who are working with web apps.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, :active works fine on chrome for android as far as I can tell. They've implemented a delay on the OS level, it seems.

Second: As I stated above, I tried adding fastclick.js back for iOS to get :active even working at all whatsoever. Once that was added, I was able to at least get :active working - but it would activate when trying to scroll.

So, because Apple treats web apps like 2nd class citizens, this is what I'm using in my production app:

CSS:

```
// Android (or anything else, which I'm not really concerned about)
// Simply use CSS! Android has built in delay to prevent trigger on scroll
body:not(.ios) { // Adding a body class using Rails 'browser' gem
  .list a:active {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }
}

// iOS only. :active would trigger on scroll (Apple treats web apps like 2nd class citizens)
body.ios {
  .list a.touch {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
// iOS only
// Roll our own delay so background color doesn't trigger on scroll
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone)/g) != null) {  

  var addTouch;
  $('.list a').on('touchend', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('touch');
    clearTimeout(addTouch);
  }).on('touchmove', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('touch');
    clearTimeout(addTouch);
  }).on('touchstart', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    addTouch = setTimeout(function() {
      that.addClass('touch');
    }, 40);
  });
}
```

Let me finish this solution with this statement: This is absolutely ridiculous. Apple - thank you for removing the 350ms touch delay: amazing! But, please fix CSS :active so scrolling is possible, just like Google did.